# Unable to switch views properly in ViewSwitcher

Tags: android, viewswitcher

I have an array of strings in my class and a `ViewSwitcher` in my layout:

```
        <ViewSwitcher
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/text_view_switcher">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/text"/>

            <WebView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/text_webview">
            </WebView>
```

I have two buttons - `Previous` and `Next` for navigation. When the user taps on `Next`, I set the text of TextView and WebView to the next element of the string array.

**The Problem**

I want to achieve the following:

```
if(string[index].contains("img src")) 
    show the Webview;          
else
    show the textview;
```

How can I do it? `ViewSwitcher.showNext` is not doing the job properly. Is there way I can associate which view to switch to using IDs?

Answer (score 0):

Although not a solution, but a simple workaround was to remove the `ViewSwitcher`, and keep both views - `TextView` and the `WebView`. Now, based upon the conditions, the visibility of the views could be toggled (`GONE` or `VISIBLE`).